# How to "properly" architect email system in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, architecture

So I recently came to be working on a cake 2.0 codebase that had already been mostly written.

It is setup with a complex and powerful email system in components. However, there are many valid cases for sending emails from a model, mostly as debugging messages to developers, and there seems to be a rule in cake that models cannot normally access components.

I don't want to write another alternative email function because this isn't dry, and I want the functionality to be shared. I also cannot instantiate a new component because it is set to inherit from a class that takes a controller in the constructor.

I don't understand how this application could be refactored to work properly in theory by cake philosophy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Components? The previous developers did it wrong. The correct way would be to use [CakeEmail](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html) and transport adapters. [The manual has a page about CakeEmail and how to write transports](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#creating-custom-transports).

It is not just a rule in Cake but in MVC in general that models should not access components. By the fact the previous devs didnt pay attention to that I assume there is more wrong with the general architecture of the app.